# WPF/MVVM/XAML DataGridView - setting cell background color based on cell value

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagridview

I need to setup the background color of a particular cell in a datagridview based on the cell's value.
In the code below, If the user is active, I want to setup the background color of the "Active" cell to green.

```
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{ Binding Path=Users }" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User ID" Binding="{Binding UserID}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Given Names" Binding="{Binding GivenNames}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Active" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Active, Converter={ StaticResource booleanToYesNoConverter} }" 
                                    Width="Auto"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I am new to WPF and MVVM, and I don't know what the best solution is. I was thinking along the lines of setting the background attribute using a value converter:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Active" 
                    Binding="{Binding Active, Converter={ StaticResource booleanToYesNoConverter} }"
                    Background="{ Binding Active, Converter={ StaticResource activeInactiveBackgroundColorConverter }}"
                    Width="Auto"/>
```

I have done this for a different control (StatusBarItem) and it works ok, but I can't do it for the datagridview. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Way by giving DataGridTextColumn Cell style

```
<DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Active}"
 Header="Active" 
  Width="Auto">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ Binding Active, Converter={ StaticResource activeInactiveBackgroundColorConverter }}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. That's exactly what I need, thank you!